# Rails renders .rjs in chrome but .erb in firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, google-chrome, rjs

I am in the view **foo** and have a remote form within it

```
<%= form_tag(foo_path, :method => :post, :remote => true, :class=>'form') do %>
```

when submitting the view some action happens and afterwards a .rjs file should rerender a partial div. In Chrome this works fine but in firefox the html.erb page is rendered again. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: just found out that if i do the rendering in the controller with render :update do |page| page.replace_html 'foo_div', render(:partial => ...) everything works fine in firefox but not in chrome anymore

Comment: the rjs works also in ie and opera, seems that firefox is the only browser that ignores it

Answer (score 0):

rjs is deprecated in rails 3.1, we should use js.erb

http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript